# CGAL Compile / Linker Error

Tags: c++, eclipse, cgal, nsight

I'm trying to set up CGAL in Nvidia's Nsight Eclipse studio (Eclipse CDT). I don't plan on using it with CUDA, however I will need to use it for another part of a project that I am working on.

The error I am getting is this:

```
/home/me/work/x64_linux/cgal/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:62: 
undefined reference to `__gmpq_init'
```

This is followed by several other identical errors regarding gmpq. I think it's a linking issue, but as far as I am aware, I'm not sure where I went wrong. My other dependencies link fine. I installed CGAL through apt-get, and followed the set-up instructions given in the manual. Perhaps I went wrong somewhere there, but long story short, I'm pretty lost in regards to getting this to work! Any help / tips are appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the solution, for anyone in the future that might stumble across this question.

For some reason, the IDE was referencing the library incorrectly, despite my inputs being correct. I simply opened a new project and migrated my files over. Adding libraries follows the standard procedure in Eclipse: Go to Project Properties -> Paths and Symbols. Add the path to the directory the library is located under to library paths, and add the library name to libraries.

Comment: short answer: `-lgmp`. Longer answer: search for "undefined reference" on this site. Also, CGAL recommends using cmake, which would handle this for you.

Comment: @Marc So I was able to get my program to link and compile with a custom cmake setup. I noticed that passing -lgmp to the target linker did not work, and I had to add the whole path to the file instead. Not sure why. I tried adding the whole path to the library in the IDE but it returns the error    `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so`  It would be nice if I could get this working in the IDE, but it seems like it can't find the file, even when given the entire path

Comment: `-l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so`: that's not how it works. "did not work": such a precise error message...

Comment: @Marc Yeah, I can read too, don't worry. The question is why the linker can't find it - It exists, it's in the directory, and I've tried to put it in other directories, to see if it fixes it / is a permissions issue. Beyond the obvious solutions I've tried, as well as what google and SO bring up, I'm not sure what else could be occurring. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, for anyone in the future that might stumble across this question.

For some reason, the IDE was referencing the library incorrectly, despite my inputs being correct. I simply opened a new project and migrated my files over. Adding libraries follows the standard procedure in Eclipse: Go to Project Properties -> Paths and Symbols. Add the path to the directory the library is located under to library paths, and add the library name to libraries. If you need clarification, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that when you are compiling your code, you should be passing a `-l` option to the compiler to link to CGAL
2. If you **are** passing a `-l` option to the compiler, make sure that either the CGAL library is accessible from a folder in your path or that you are passing the full path to the CGAL library.

There isn't much more I can say without seeing your build setup.

Comment: Noob question: Is there any way to nicely export the build setup under my project properties to stackoverflow? If not is there anything in particular you'd like to examine? I've tried the full path; doesn't work from within the IDE but works with custom cmake.

Comment: @ak47777 I'm at work currently but when I get home I'll download eclipse cdt and walk you through how to link a library

Comment: No need, I managed to fix it a while back! Thanks for your help though.